# Graph 1 hangs when function called second time

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I want to generate graphs dynamically when I click on a button. My problem is when I click the button second time, the first graphs blocks displaying data.
The problem is with setInterval used within addChart function but I can't figure out how to rectify the issue. Is there some sanity in my logic or not?

```
<script>
    function addChart() {
        chartCount++;
        var name = document.getElementById("chartName").value;
        chartDict[name] = chartCount;
        chart[chartCount] = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer" + chartCount, {
            title: {
                text: name
            },
            axisY: {
                includeZero: false,
                maximum: 70
            },
            axisX: {
                valueFormatString: "hh:mm tt"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dps[chartCount]
            }]
        });
        updateChart[chartCount] = function(count) {
            count = count || 1;

            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {

                dps[chartCount].push({
                    x: xVal[chartCount],
                    y: yVal[chartCount]
                });
                xVal[chartCount] = new Date()
                //console.log(xVal)
                //xVal++;
            }

            if (dps[chartCount].length > dataLength) {
                dps[chartCount].shift();
            }

            chart[chartCount].render();
        };
        intervals[chartCount] = setInterval(updateChart[chartCount], 1000)

    } 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below workaround  :

Remove the chart's inner content from DOM before reassigning the new values to chart element
Below is link to use remove() method of jquery:

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: I tried that but only one setInterval function works of multiple graphs .

Comment: sorry this link is not working for me,unable to open the link